# google maps resposive with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

how can i make my google maps responsive with bootstrap
i have a map that displays fullscreen. its fine on browser 
but the mobile asthetics is not good.i need a responsive 
map that fits the viewport

```
#map{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

in a jumbotron. this is a quick fix but need fully responsive.

```
<div class="container-fluid"  >
<div class="row-fluid">
<h1>Landing Page</h1>
Latitude : {{lat}}
Longitude : {{lon}}
Accuracy : {{accuracy}}
</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
 <div id="map"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: check this one http://codepen.io/iamnumber2407/pen/nBdsv

Comment: another working example https://niklausgerber.com/blog/responsive-google-or-bing-maps/